# java.lang.NullPointerException is caused by getContentResolver() in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I have this code below. It works before in Activity. Now I want to convert it to Fragment. I have tried **context.getContentResolver();** or **getActivity().getContentResolver();** But it doesn't work. How to fix this ?

```
public class MyFragmentA extends Fragment {

//song list variables
    private ArrayList<Song> songList;
    private ListView songView;
    public Context context;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);

    //retrieve list view
            songView = (ListView) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.song_list);
            //instantiate list
            songList = new ArrayList<Song>();
            //get songs from device
            getSongList();
            //sort alphabetically by title
            Collections.sort(songList, new Comparator<Song>(){
                public int compare(Song a, Song b){
                    return a.getTitle().compareTo(b.getTitle());
                }
            });
            //create and set adapter
            SongAdapter songAdt = new SongAdapter(this.getActivity(), songList);
            songView.setAdapter(songAdt);

    return myFragmentView;
}


public void getSongList() {

ContentResolver musicResolver = context.getContentResolver();
Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);
----------------------
----------------------
----------------------
----------------------
            }
        }
    }
```

This my logcat trace

```
11-25 20:29:34.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4092): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-25 20:29:34.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4092): Process: com.ddev.delta, PID: 4092
11-25 20:29:34.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4092): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ddev.delta/com.ddev.delta.AndroidNavigationTabsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-25 20:29:34.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4092):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2212)
11-25 20:29:34.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4092):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
11-25 20:29:34.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4092):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
11-25 20:29:34.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4092):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
11-25 20:29:34.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4092):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-25 20:29:34.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4092):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-25 20:29:34.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4092):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
11-25 20:29:34.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4092):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-25 20:29:34.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4092):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-25 20:29:34.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4092):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
11-25 20:29:34.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4092):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
11-25 20:29:34.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4092):     at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
11-25 20:29:34.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4092):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-25 20:29:34.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4092): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-25 20:29:34.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4092):     at com.ddev.delta.AndroidNavigationTabsActivity.onCreate(AndroidNavigationTabsActivity.java:17)
11-25 20:29:34.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4092):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
11-25 20:29:34.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4092):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-25 20:29:34.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4092):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
11-25 20:29:34.001: E/AndroidRuntime(4092):     ... 12 more
```

Comment: Which is line 57 in your code? Exception is occurring at `line 57`.

Comment: context is null... use getActivity().getContentResolver();

Comment: There's another NPE in `AndroidNavigationTabsActivity.onCreate(AndroidNavigationTabsActivity.java:17)`

Answer (score 6):

> ```
> ContentResolver musicResolver = context.getContentResolver();
> ```

Your `context` is not initialized.

Since you're in a fragment lifecycle callback `onCreateView()` or a method called from one, you can use `getActivity()` for a `Context`:

```
ContentResolver musicResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
```

Remove the `Context context;` declaration as unnecessary, too.

Comment: Feel free to explain what "doesn't work" means to you. Edit the question to do so.

Comment: Please include the complete exception stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Context context;
```

Your context is **null**, try use `getActivity().getContentResolver();`

Answer (score 0):

Initialize context object  in onCreateView() before call getSongList():

```
context = getActivity();
```

**OR**

```
getActivity().getContentResolver()
```

Comment: the error still the same. java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: I just convert it from Activity to Fragment and the problem is getContentResolver() make it crash.

Answer (score 0):

Create an object of Activity and then initialize it by

```
Activity a=getActivity();
```

And then use

```
ContentResolver musicResolver = a.getContentResolver();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Following for these Cases:

- Application :- getApplicationContext()
- activity :- context
- Fragment :- getActivity()